# Basic jQuery Slider adding active class to slider li

Tags: jquery

I am trying out a plugin called [Basic jQuery Slider](http://www.basic-slider.com/) - I am trying to work out if i can get it to show an active class in on the shown slide. However it does not seem to be working, even though by the looks of things that, `showmarkers : true` was supposed to do that from what i can see.

HTML:

```
<div id="banner-fade">
    <ul class="bjqs">
        <li><!-- Any content you like --></li>
        <li><!-- Can go inside these slides--></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#banner-fade').bjqs({
     animtype : 'slide',
     animduration: 950,
     width : 1280,
     height : 483,
     showmarkers : true
});
```

EDIT:

Sorry the # in the div id was my mistake when writing this question. It's not in my working code. It appears that the markers are the number pagination so i need to find out if it is possible to instead get an active class on the slider `li` that your currently viewing instead of the pagination.

Comment: Try `<div id="banner-fade">`, lose the `#`

Comment: Definately needs the #, it's targeting the div ok, as the slider works. I think i can see that it's adding the class to the slider controls instead of the slider li itself.

Answer (score 0):

just remove **"#"** from div

```
<div id="banner-fade">
```

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake, i wrote it wrong when writing the question. It's not in my actual code.

Comment: so what your question i cant understand what you really need?

Comment: Well it's adding an active class to the pagination controls not the actual li of the slider. I could do with the class on the slider li

Answer (score 0):

The plugin does *not* support that behaviour, but it is relatively simple to add it.

[Here is a modified version of the plugin](https://gist.github.com/DerFlatulator/7544093)

When the `showmarkers` setting is true, it now adds the `active-marker` class to the current marker, **as well as** an `active` class to the current `<li>`.

### Code changed

Add this to `conf_slides()` ([l370-371](https://gist.github.com/DerFlatulator/7544093#file-bjqs-1-3-modified-js-L370))

```
if (settings.showmarkers)
    $slides.eq(state.currentslide - 1).addClass('active');
```

Add this to `go()` in two places: ([l645-646](https://gist.github.com/DerFlatulator/7544093#file-bjqs-1-3-modified-js-L645), [l679-680](https://gist.github.com/DerFlatulator/7544093#file-bjqs-1-3-modified-js-L679))

```
$slides.removeClass('active');
$slides.eq(state.nextindex).addClass('active');
```